# Embedded Youtube video autoplays on some computers and not on others

Tags: web, youtube, embed

I have an embedded Youtube video in a Wordpress page. On my client's computer it starts autoplaying as soon as the page is loaded. He's using Google Chrome.

On other computers the video doesn't autoplay (I've tried on multiple computers with Chrome, Firefox, IE, Opera)

The embed URL doesn't contain the "autoplay" parameter.

Any idea what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the autoplay parameter and specifically set it the way you want it to.

Comment: The client will be able to add his own videos and ideally I wouldn't want him messing with the embed code.